# OpenLDAP: Is a duplicate uidNumber permitted?

Tags: openldap

I am new to OpenLDAP. I am creating some users (`posixAccount` `ObjectClass`) and I set two of them to use the same `uidNumber`.

There was no complaint from OpenLDAP. Is that normal? I would have expected each needs to be unique.

A closely related question: Can I assign any random number to the `uidNumber` attribute?

Comment: Hi! I made a few minor changes to your question. Most notably, I rephrased your title as a question, and clarified your question based on the title. While I was at it, I went ahead and marked inline references as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can assign any integer to `uidNumber`. You can even assign an integer which might be outside the range of `uid_t` on the systems that use it. That's up to you to manage.

There is no uniqueness checking by default. If you want this, look at the [slapo-unique(5)](https://openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-unique&apropos=0&sektion=5&manpath=OpenLDAP+2.4-Release&arch=default&format=html) overlay.